# AngularJs read json file not recognized

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I  am testing `AngularJS`. I am trying to read a `json` file with `http.get` and show it in a `ng-repeat`.

I have two problems...

First, the file with .json extension is not recognized. I have to rename it with .js extension

Second, the format elements in the file are not recognize. Repeater is filled with empty rows.

Here is my Angular.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
        .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.loadData = function () {
                $http.get("productData.js").success(function (data) {
                    $scope.products = data;
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-hide="products.length">
                        <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in products">
                        <td>{{name}}</td>
                        <td>{{category}}</td>
                        <td>{{price | currency}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loadData()">
                    Load Data
                </button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my ProductData.js

```html
[{ "name": "Apples", "category": "Fruit", "price": 1.20, "expiry": 10 },
{ "name": "Bananas", "category": "Fruit", "price": 2.42, "expiry": 7 },
{ "name": "Pears", "category": "Fruit", "price": 2.02, "expiry": 6 },
{ "name": "Tuna", "category": "Fish", "price": 20.45, "expiry": 3 },
{ "name": "Salmon", "category": "Fish", "price": 17.93, "expiry": 2 },
{ "name": "Trout", "category": "Fish", "price": 12.93, "expiry": 4 }]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The file name should be .json only. Post snap shot of your network tab in developer tools that makes the call

Comment: How can i get network tab in developer tools? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file as productdata.json. and change your code according to it

```
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
        .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.loadData = function () {
                $http.get("productData.json").success(function (data) {
                    $scope.products = data;
                });
            }
        });
```

Also if you are using angularjs version above 1.3 replace .Success with .Then, because .Success has been deprecated

Comment: If I use .json, the file is not  found. It is like json extension is not recongnize. Thanks

Comment: @Diego, does your server allow JSON files to be served to the client?

Comment: I am working only in my PC, how can I check it? Thanks

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found why it does not appear... It was my mistake.. I had to replace

```html
  <tr ng-repeat="item in products">
                        <td>{{name}}</td>
                        <td>{{category}}</td>
                        <td>{{price | currency}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

for this one

```html
  <tr ng-repeat="item in products">
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.category}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

I have forgotten to add `item.`

Anyway.. I could not find why my PC do not accept `.json` file... If I put those file in IIS directory and run it from IIS, it Works fine.. But it does not work from outside IIS.

Comment: you need to run as local host to get the json file. use brackets and click on the right top lightning icon to test locally.